# Set resource for JNDI on $TOMCAT/conf/context.xml

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

I have a problem, when a set a resource on $TOMCAT/conf/context.xml for config a JNDI, and then try to run a proyect, this can't be deployed.

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->
<Resource
    name=“jdbc/UsersDB”
    auth=”Container”
    type=“javax.sql.DataSource”
    maxActive=“100”
    maxIdle=“30”
    maxWait=“10000”
    driverClassName=“com.mysql.jdbc.Driver”
    url=“jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database”
    username=“root”
    password=“hg”
    />
</Context>
```

log tomcat. error that appear before I try to run the project:

```
0-Jul-2015 09:56:02.359 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Desplieque del descriptor de configuración /Users/imaq/trabajo/apache-tomcat-8.0.22/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
30-Jul-2015 09:56:02.428 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.fatalError Parse Fatal Error at line 27 column 16: El tipo de elemento "Resource" debe ir seguido de una de estas especificaciones de atributo: ">" o "/>".
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/imaq/trabajo/apache-tomcat-8.0.22/conf/context.xml; lineNumber: 45; columnNumber: 16; El tipo de elemento "Resource" debe ir seguido de una de estas especificaciones de atributo: ">" o "/>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.seekCloseOfStartTag(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1395)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1328)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1451)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: There's any error in tomcat logs? Have you placed `mysql` drivers into `lib` folder in tomcat?

Comment: I check the log and was a error. I resolved the error. The problem was the cuotes, I set all again and works. thanks.

Comment: In order to help other users who might have the same problem, could you please include the logged error in your question and make a proper answer to your own question (this is allowed) ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the quotes, I put it all again and works.